# tutorials for developing facebook applications in android

Tags: android, facebook

Can any one please suggest me good tutorials (other than official) for learning basics to develop Facebook apps in Android.
I am searching in internet but I am failing to get good ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checkout this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android

This will surely help you.

Comment: now I am working with that only. Can u please suggest me more...